# Tuya very locally

Tags: wireless-networking

I configured a Tuya [Wifi Mini Smart Switch](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/1005003637851837.html)to connect to a Raspberry Pi 4 wifi access point, turned off the Raspberry and the Smart Life app on a phone connected to a different wifi can still control the switch (I can only turn on and off, I cannot set a schedule). I played around a bit and it seems that the app needs wifi and bluetooth (?) enabled. With wifi off I can still control the switch, only going into airplane mode breaks the connection. However, turning on wifi (and bt) again allows control. And the Tuya device is not connected to any network, local or global.

Anyone know how this is possible?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Tuya will connect locally over WiFi or Bluetooth [as far as I'm aware, BT is only used to initiate the device], but also globally via tuya.com This is what makes schedules etc work, and how you can control them from anywhere in the world.

Comment: The Tuya device is not connected to any wifi network (Raspberry is turned off), and the smartphone is connected to a completely different router. A local LAN connection is not possible. Tuya is also using BT for device control, not just initiation (?).

Comment: Hmm… I should have checked earlier - it **does** work with just BT. The instructions said it was used for setup, didn't mention it would work for control too.

Answer (score 0):

Empirically tested, a Tuya device will use any connection method available to it - Bluetooth, LAN or WAN WiFi.

Timer & scene setups appear to require it to be able to see the WAN [in effect, to be able to reach tuya.com]. Local control will work over local WiFi, same subnet, or Bluetooth.